# Are hashCodes unique for Strings?

Tags: java, hashcode

Recently, I came across a piece of code, where `Map<Integer, String>` is used, where `Integer`(key) is `hashCode` of some string and `String` value corresponding to that.

Is this right thing to do? Because now, `equals` will not be called for the `String` when calling `get`. (`get` is also done using `hashCode()` method on String object.

Or, hashCode(s) are unique for unique Strings?

I checked `equals` od `String` class. There is logic written for that. I am confused.

Comment: it is useless thing to do, hashes for strings are not unique

Comment: It is a wrong thing to do, of course; the equals/hashCode contract stipulates that two equal objects must have the same hashcode but it does not guarantee that two unequal objects must have different hashcodes.

Comment: So, I was right about it. :)

Comment: Quick question @Batty - how many different `String` values are there?  And how many different values can the `hashCode` of a `String` take?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A HashMap **does** use `equals()` to compare keys. It only uses `hashCode()` to find the bucket where the key is located, and thus drastically reduce the number of keys to compare with `equals()`.

Obviously, `hashCode()` can't produce unique values, since int is limited to 2^32 distinct values, and there are an infinity of possible String values.

In conclusion, the result of `hashCode()` is not a good fit for a key of a `Map`.

Comment: Everything is finite: Strings are arrays of chars, the maximum length of an array in Java is just under Integer.MAX_VALUE, and chars are unsigned 2-byte integers.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the OP's question.  The code should probably be using Map<String, String>.  In general, it should not be doing it's own hashing of the key String.  Unless of course there is a good reason specific to that code.

Comment: Generating hash codes of any strings is based on a specific hash function. Because of the limitation on the size of these numbers, according to the pigeon hole principle, there will definitely be certain collision in the hashing. It can't be done away with completely.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: touche.

Answer (score 7):

No, they are not unique, eg "FB" and "Ea" both have hashCode = 2236

Comment: Yeah, that's the other problem, it's not like you only create a collision for any kind of weird string, `hashCode()` is not well defined and may even differ between implementations. I'm not sure an example merits a separate answer though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct, as `hashCode()` will have collisions. As `hashCode()` is not well defined, it may have collisions for any pair of strings. So you cannot use that. If you require a unique pointer to a string then you can use a cryptographic hash as key:

The following code shows how to do this:

```
/**
 * Immutable class that represents a unique key for a string. This unique key
 * can be used as a key in a hash map, without the likelihood of a collision:
 * generating the same key for a different String. Note that you should first
 * check if keeping a key to a reference of a string is feasible, in that case a
 * {@link Set} may suffice.
 * <P>
 * This class utilizes SHA-512 to generate the keys and uses
 * {@link StandardCharsets#UTF_8} for the encoding of the strings. If a smaller
 * output size than 512 bits (64 bytes) is required then the leftmost bytes of
 * the SHA-512 hash are used. Smaller keys are therefore contained in with
 * larger keys over the same String value.
 * <P>
 * Note that it is not impossible to create collisions for key sizes up to 8-20
 * bytes.
 * 
 * @author owlstead
 */
public final class UniqueKey implements Serializable {

    public static final int MIN_DIGEST_SIZE_BYTES = 8;
    public static final int MAX_DIGEST_SIZE_BYTES = 64;

    /**
     * Creates a unique key for a string with the maximum size of 64 bytes.
     * 
     * @param input
     *            the input, not null
     * @return the generated instance
     */
    public static UniqueKey createUniqueKey(final CharSequence input) {
        return doCreateUniqueKey(input, MAX_DIGEST_SIZE_BYTES);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a unique key for a string with a size of 8 to 64 bytes.
     * 
     * @param input
     *            the input, not null
     * @param outputSizeBytes
     *            the output size
     * @return the generated instance
     */
    public static UniqueKey createUniqueKey(final CharSequence input,
            final int outputSizeBytes) {
        return doCreateUniqueKey(input, outputSizeBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof UniqueKey)) {
            return false;
        }
        final UniqueKey that = (UniqueKey) obj;
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(this.key).equals(ByteBuffer.wrap(that.key));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(this.key).hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * Outputs an - in itself - unique String representation of this key.
     * 
     * @return the string <CODE>"{key: [HEX ENCODED KEY]}"</CODE>
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // non-optimal but readable conversion to hexadecimal
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.key.length * 2);
        sb.append("{Key: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.key.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", this.key[i]));
        }
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Makes it possible to retrieve the underlying key data (e.g. to use a
     * different encoding).
     * 
     * @return the data in a read only ByteBuffer
     */
    public ByteBuffer asReadOnlyByteBuffer() {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(this.key).asReadOnlyBuffer();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 512;

    // byte array instead of ByteBuffer to support serialization
    private final byte[] key;

    private static UniqueKey doCreateUniqueKey(final CharSequence input,
            final int outputSizeBytes) {

        // --- setup digest

        final MessageDigest digestAlgorithm;
        try {
            // note: relatively fast on 64 bit systems (faster than SHA-256!)
            digestAlgorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "SHA-256 should always be avialable in a Java RE");
        }

        // --- validate input parameters

        if (outputSizeBytes < MIN_DIGEST_SIZE_BYTES
                || outputSizeBytes > MAX_DIGEST_SIZE_BYTES) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unique key size either too small or too big");
        }

        // --- setup loop

        final CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder();
        final CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(input);
        final ByteBuffer encodedBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
        CoderResult coderResult;

        // --- loop over all characters
        // (instead of encoding everything to byte[] at once - peak memory!)

        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            coderResult = encoder.encode(buffer, encodedBuffer, false);
            if (coderResult.isError()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Invalid code point in input string");
            }
            encodedBuffer.flip();
            digestAlgorithm.update(encodedBuffer);
            encodedBuffer.clear();
        }

        coderResult = encoder.encode(buffer, encodedBuffer, true);
        if (coderResult.isError()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid code point in input string");
        }
        encodedBuffer.flip();
        digestAlgorithm.update(encodedBuffer);
        // no need to clear encodedBuffer if generated locally

        // --- resize result if required

        final byte[] digest = digestAlgorithm.digest();
        final byte[] result;
        if (outputSizeBytes == digest.length) {
            result = digest;
        } else {
            result = Arrays.copyOf(digest, outputSizeBytes);
        }

        // --- and return the final, possibly resized, result

        return new UniqueKey(result);
    }

    private UniqueKey(final byte[] key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing it's own hashing of the key String, that code risks the chance that two different key strings will generate the same integer map key and the code will fail in some situations.

In general, the code should probably be using `Map<String,String>`.

However it is possible that the author is doing that for a good (ie deliberate) reason and it is not a bug.  We can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: It would be such a bad code smell that my eyes would be watering though. If there wasn't a very specific comment right above it, it would never pass any review that I would do.

Answer (score 0):

A hashCode is to increase the performance of collections. For example with an Set, which contains unique items. When adding a new item, the hashCode will be used to detect if the item already exists in the Set.

In the event of a collision, we'll fall through to a (usually) slower equals comparison.

Therefore, its important for performance that a hashCode should return a distinct value. Of much greater importance is that an object's hashCode is consistent across invocations, given the same internal state.

Therefore it is not wise use hashCode as keys in a map! They are not unique.